# How can I trigger an action from a different controller for dynamic content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, controller, routes

Im having a dynamic header depending on the view and action of the controller and it works fine with the actions in "welcomes_controller". But Im not able to trigger a action from a different controller in this case posts_controller.

**How can I trigger it correctly?** Thanks in advance.

```
<% if params[:action] == 'index' %>
  <%= image_tag("header_background.jpg", alt: "header background", :class => "header_background") %>
<% elsif params[:action] == 'trading' %>
  <%= image_tag("trading_background.jpg", alt: "trading background", :class => "header_background") %>

<% elseif ... HOW TO TRIGGER A ACTION FROM A DIFFERENT CONTROLLER? %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Try use `action_name` instead of `params[:action]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two helpers easily availalbe for this: [`controller_name`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class) and [`action_name`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/Scope/action_name). You can use a combo of these for conditional rendering.

That said, personally I feel this is a lot of clutter for the view - I can't help feeling this would be better set elsewhere. In a very simple sense, you could add the following in your controllers:

```
def index
  @header_image = "header_background.jpg"
end

def trading
  @header_image = "trading_background.jpg"
end
```

And then in the view:

```
image_tag(@header_image, alt: @header_image, :class => "header_background")
```

---

Alternatively, you could follow a convention for your images:

```
image_tag("#{controller_name}/#{action_name}.jpg", alt: action_name, :class => "header_background")
```

Then ensure your header images are stored in a folder named after the controller, named after the relevant action.

I'd strongly lean towards the latter.

---

Update: one final option would be to define a helper that handles this, something like, in you view:

```
= header_image_tag
```

And somewhere within your `/helpers` folder something akin to:

```
def header_image_tag
  image_path = case controller_name
               when "controller_one"
                 "header_background.jpg" if action_name == "index"
                 "trading_background.jpg" if action_name == "trading"
               when "controller_two"
                 # ...
               else
                 "default_image.jpg"
               end
  image_tag image_path, alt: # ...etc
end
```

I *think* the helper has access to `controller_name` and `action_name`, though if not you could pass these as args to `header_image_tag`, or pass the `request` as an arg and access `request.controller_name` and `request.action_name`.

Let me know what you think and how you get on.

Comment: Hey thanks for your detailed answer! I could not make it work with the convention for the image_tag so I used the method with the variables in the controller it worked perfectly! THX!

Answer (score 1):

For this I use this code.  This should work for what you are trying to achieve.

```
<% if controller.action_name.to_s == "index" %>
```

Also keep in mind, if you need to be more granular with the specific controller you want to target you can also add the controller name to the check.

```
<% if controller.controller_name.to_s == "posts" && controller.action_name.to_s == "index" %>
```